# ngrx/store - testing, throw TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular8, angular-unit-test

Here is my ts file:

```
this.store.pipe(select(subscribe.getRegCategories)).pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(data => {
            if (data && data.length) {
                this.allRegCategories = data;
            }
        });
```

when i go for testing getting error as:

```
this.store.pipe(select(subscribe.getRegCategories)).pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(data => {

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
```

how to provide the pipe here? what is the correct way to solve this?

Here is my test spec file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ShellViewProgMgmtComponent } from './shell-view-prog-mgmt.component';
import { ViewProgMgmtComponent } from './../../components/view-prog-mgmt/view-prog-mgmt.component';
import * as actions from './../../state/actions/setup-config.actions';

describe('ShellViewProgMgmtComponent', () => {
    let component: ShellViewProgMgmtComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ShellViewProgMgmtComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ShellViewProgMgmtComponent, ViewProgMgmtComponent],
            imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule],
            providers: [
            {
                provide: Store,
                useValue: {
                    dispatch: jest.fn(),
                    pipe: jest.fn()
                }
            }
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShellViewProgMgmtComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    describe('ngOnInit()', () => {

        it('should dispatch an event resetEditPage action in ngOnit lifecycle', () => {

            const store = TestBed.get(Store);
            const action = actions.resetEditPage();
            const spy = jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch');

            fixture.detectChanges();
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(action);

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Have you created an instance of the Store type? like we do in angular constructor!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't mock your own Store.

Instead use `MockStore` and/or mock selectors, as it will make your life easier.
You can take a look at the implementation to find how you have to create a mock store, if this is what you want.

For more info about testing projects that use NgRx, see [Testing an NgRx project](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/testing-an-ngrx-project).

Comment: @timdeschryer, thanks for your advice!! yes I implemented as for the doc. but getting an issue as this user get: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172016/typeerror-actual-subscribe-is-not-a-function` - can you help me to sort this? I don't want to create new question the issue match like me